# PySpark - monotonically_increasing_id() not increasing consecutively

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write a PySpark script that would rank the customers by revenue for each retailer the customer belongs under. My current solution is following:

```
unique_retailers = RETAILERS.select('ID').distinct().rdd.map(lambda r: r[0]).collect()
CUSTOMERS = CUSTOMERS.orderBy(sf.col('REVENUE'), ascending=False)
for i in unique_retailers:
    RANK = CUSTOMERS.select('ID').where(sf.substring(sf.col('ID'), 0, 1) == sf.lit(i)).withColumn('RANK_'+i, sf.monotonically_increasing_id())
    RANK.show()
    CUSTOMERS = CUSTOMERS.join(RANK, ['ID'], 'left')
CUSTOMERS.show()
```

Where in each `CUSTOMERS.ID` the first character is `RETAILERS.ID` of the particular retailer. However the `monotonically_increasing_id())` is behaving rather unexpectedly, where I would expect values follow the pattern `v(k+1) = v(k) + 1`, they seem to diverge wildly for some reason. Example can be seen below:

```
    +--------+--------------------+
    |ID      |RANK_1              |
    +--------+--------------------+
    |1_502765|                   0|
    |1_522762|                   1|
    |1_532768|         17179869184|
    |1_452763|         68719476736|
    |1_522766|         94489280512|
    |1_512769|        214748364800|
    |1_542766|        223338299392|
    |1_452766|        549755813888|
    |1_542769|        549755813889|
    |1_512766|        721554505728|
    |1_132760|        962072674304|
    |1_522761|        996432412672|
    |1_542764|       1065151889408|
    |1_172765|       1151051235328|
    |1_542762|       1194000908288|
    |1_542765|       1245540515840|
    |1_532766|       1254130450432|
    |1_542760|       1400159338496|
    |1_172767|       1408749273088|
    |1_412764|       1511828488192|
    +--------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monotonically does not mean consecutive. What you experience is actually the expected behavior. Have a look at the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions)... and keep in mind that spark is distributed so generating consecutive indices, although not impossible, is not trivial.

> `scala def monotonically_increasing_id(): Column`
>
> A column expression that generates monotonically increasing 64-bit
>   integers.
>
> The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and
>   unique, **but not consecutive**. The current implementation puts the
>   partition ID in the upper 31 bits, and the record number within each
>   partition in the lower 33 bits. The assumption is that the data frame
>   has less than 1 billion partitions, and each partition has less than 8
>   billion records.
>
> As an example, consider a DataFrame with two partitions, each with 3
>   records. This expression would return the following IDs:
>
> `0, 1, 2, 8589934592 (1L << 33), 8589934593, 8589934594.`